# Can I change my response data in OutputFormatter in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a simple feature to make the first action act like the second one.

```
public IActionResult GetMessage()
{
    return "message";
}


public IActionResult GetMessageDataModel()
{
    return new MessageDataModel("message");
}
```

First idea came to my mind was to extend `SystemTextJsonOutputFormater`, and wrap `context.Object` with my data model in `WriteResponseBodyAsync`, but the action is marked `sealed`.

Then I tried to override `WriteAsync` but `context.Object` doesn't have protected setter, either.

Is there anyway I can achieve this by manipulating OutputFormatter?
Or I have another option instead of a custom `OutputFormatter`?

Comment: `trying to create a simple feature to make the first action act like the second one` Can you clarify the actual scenario that requires doing this?

Comment: Sometime I want to return a simple message to front-end user, but for some reason they prefer every response in a same format like ```{"return":"some message I write.","code":1}```, hence I want this feature to achieve this instead of creating ```MessageDataModel``` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason they prefer every response in a same format like `{"return":"some message I write.","code":1}`, hence I want this feature to achieve this instead of creating `MessageDataModel` every time.

Based on your description and requirement, it seems that you'd like to generate unified-format data globally instead of achieving it in each action's code logic. To achieve it, you can try to implement it in action filter, like below.

```
public class MyCustomFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // implement code logic here 
        // based on your actual scenario

        // get original message
        // generate new instance of MessageDataModel

        //example: 

        var mes = context.Result as JsonResult;

        var model = new MessageDataModel
        {
            Code = 1,
            Return = mes.Value.ToString()
        };

        context.Result = new JsonResult(model);
    }
```

Apply it on specific action(s)

```
[MyCustomFilter]
public IActionResult GetMessage()
{
    return Json("message");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is absoultely what I want.